# git branch --merged using plumbing commands

Tags: git

Is there a way to achieve the equivalent of

  `git branch --merged`

using git plumbing commands?

I know there are commands like `git for-each-ref` which gives you the commit hashes and their corresponding ref names. Is there a command to tell whether a commit is reachable from another commit (which is basically what `--merged` do)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to do the equivalent of `git branch --merged` in scripts but don't want to deal with the porcelain output (e.g., "* master", "origin/HEAD->origin/master", etc)

Comment: Well, you could `strace -f -o /tmp/branch.log -e trace=execve git branch --merged`, and see what `git` actually does. Alternatively, let `git` do it for you: `GIT_TRACE=2 git branch --merged`.

Comment: If you don't want the output, send it to `/dev/null`... or just tell it to be quiet (`-q`)

Answer (score 3):

`git merge-base --independent X Y Z` will tell you which of those are not yet merged to another branch.

In addition, `git merge-base --is-ancestor X Y` will tell you whether X is an ancestor of Y, but that's an inefficient way to implement `git branch --merged` because you'll need to run it N^2 times for N branches.

Comment: Apparently this is relatively new functionality; the old way of doing it was to run `git merge-base X Y` and check to see if the merge base was equal to X.

Answer (score 0):

The "plumbing" equivalent to `git branch --merged` is using `git for-each-ref`.

Something like this

```bash
git for-each-ref --merged HEAD |
  cut -f 2 |
  sed -n '/^refs\/heads\//{s@@@;p}'
```

and then if you want remotes you change it to something like

```bash
git for-each-ref --merged |
  cut -f 2 |
  sed -n '/^refs\/remotes\//{s@@@;p}'
```